# Why does ls still show the file excluded via GLOBIGNORE?

Tags: bash, shell

File missing with `echo` but present with `ls -a`.  Why?

```
bojan@hyperion:~$ touch .ignoramus
bojan@localhost:~$ ls -al | grep ignor
-rw-rw-r--  1 bojan bojan     0 Apr 19 19:05 .ignoramus
bojan@localhost:~$ GLOBIGNORE=".ignoramus";
bojan@localhost:~$ echo .i*
.icons
bojan@localhost:~$ ls -al | grep ignor
-rw-rw-r--  1 bojan bojan     0 Apr 19 19:05 .ignoramus
bojan@localhost:~$ echo $GLOBIGNORE
.ignoramus
```

The ls man says `-a` only shows hidden, doesn't mention GLOBIGNORE.

```
   -a, --all
          do not ignore entries starting with .

ls (GNU coreutils) 8.23
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: because your ls command didn't have anything to glob?

Comment: see ls's matching behavior with "ls -ld .i*"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting `GLOBIGNORE` has no influence on `ls`, and the `ls` manual doesn't mention `GLOBIGNORE`, because `ls` doesn't care about `GLOBIGNORE`. It's a feature of bash only, which makes it omit some files in glob patterns.

With `echo .i*`, bash is listing the files, so `GLOBIGNORE` kicks in. With `ls -a`, `ls` is listing the files, so `GLOBIGNORE` is irrelevant.

GNU `ls` has a similar feature: you can pass a pattern to ignore as a command line option.

```
ls -a -I .ignoramus
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable GLOBIGNORE is a feature of bash to affect only **expanded** files.

In other words: only when a glob is used, a GLOBIGNORE has an effect.

A glob is an alternative name for "pathname expansion" with characters *,?, [...].

A command like `ls -al` or simple `ls` are not the result of a glob, therefore a GLOBIGNORE is not used.

However, a command like `ls -d *` makes use of a glob and GLOBIGNORE is in effect.

There are two other ways in which setting (or unsetting) GLOBIGNORE will affect "pathname expansions":

GLOBIGNORE is set and not null:

1. File names `.`  and `..`  are always ignored.
2. The dotglob shell option gets set (files starting with dot will match).

Unsetting GLOBIGNORE

1. File names `.''  and`..''  are NOT ignored.
2. The dotglob option gets disabled.